# rdd.checkpoint is skipped in spark job

Tags: java, apache-spark

Hi I am trying to run a long sparkjob that often fails due to StackoverflowError. The job reads a parquetfile and creates an rdd in a foreach loop. After doing some research I thought creating a checkpoint for each rdd would help me solve my memory issues. (I have tried different memory, overhead memory, paralellism, repartition and found the most working settings for the job, however sometimes it still fails depending on the load on our cluster.)

Now to my real issue. I am trying to create checkpoints, by first reading in the parquet creating an RDD, then caching it, running checkpoint function and then calling the action first to make the checkpoint happen. No checkpoints are created in the path that I have specified and it the YARN UI it says that stage is skipped. Can anyone help me understand the problem :)

```
  ctx.getSparkContext().setCheckpointDir("/tmp/checkpoints");
    public static void writeHhidToCouchbase(DataFrameContext ctx, List<String> filePathsStrings)  {
    filePathsStrings
        .forEach(filePath -> {
          JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd =
              UidHhidPerDay.getParquetFromPath(ctx, filePath);
          rdd.cache();
          rdd.checkpoint();
          rdd.first();
          rdd.foreachPartition(p -> {
            CrumbsClient client = getClient();
            p.forEachRemaining(uids -> {
              Crumbs crumbs = client.getAsync(uids._1)
                  .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                  .toBlocking()
                  .first();
              String hHid = uids._2;
              if (hHid != null) {
                crumbs.getOrCreateSingletonCrumb(HouseholdCrumb.class).setHouseholdId(hHid);
                client.putSync(crumbs);
              }
            });
            client.shutdown();
          });
        });
}
```

The checkpoint is created once in the first iteration but never again.
KR

Comment: Not sure if releveant, but it looks like the call to `rdd.checkpoint()` is redundant, the rdd has no parent lineage to truncate. And as such will not help with memory usage.

Comment: @ImDarrenG thanks! Could you please show me how it could be done in code?

Comment: You can just remove the call to checkpoint(), it isn't going to help you.

Comment: Ok, but is there any other way to ensure the job finishes successfully? And could you please explain what you mean with the rdd has no parent lineage to truncate :) I'm a bit new to spark. KR

Comment: Please can you supply more details on the stackoverflowerror?

Comment: I don't always get them, and job is sometimes successful so I don't have it right now. I am trying to tune/fix the job to run stabil every time.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake the partitions are actually created. The "first" partition that I mentioned above is a directory with the partitions inside. Because of a directory name like 8f987639-d5c8-46b8-a1e0-37081f9f8e00 I became confused. However looking into the lineage comment from @ImDarrenG gave me some more insights. I created a new repartitioned RDD from the first one that I cache and checkpoint. This gave made the application more stabile with no failures.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd =
          UidHhidPerDay.getParquetFromPath(ctx, filePath);
      rdd.cache();
      rdd.checkpoint();
      rdd.first();
      JavaPairRDD<String, String> rddToCompute = rdd.repartition(72);
      rddToCompute.foreachPartition...
```

Comment: Glad you found the issue. I'd be interested to see if it is stable without rdd.cache(); rdd.checkpoint(); rdd.first(); but if it ain't broke - don't fix it!

Comment: Thanks, it was not stable I would always get x nr of failed tasks foreachpartition :), but now I get none :)